# Socket IO ssl standalone no http/https server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i want to connect my socket IO server over ssl, i do not need a http server i want the standalone, can someone explain me that, i search everywere they only talk about http and https servers.

Answer (score 0):

Socket io uses `http` or `https` to create the socket connection. The socket client sends an [upgrade header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header) in the `http/https` request which causes the request to turn into a `websocket` request. You only need to respond to requests with the upgrade header (eg, you can ignore `GET` requests to `/`) but you do need a `http` or `https` server.